# Which surah in the Quran is the Syrian poet Adonis is referring to here?

Tags: quran, tafseer, source-identification

The Syrian poet Adonis in an [interview](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/bookreviews/9086902/A-Page-in-the-Life-Adonis.html) referring to censorship in Syria said:

> “This is a problem of Muslims, not the Koran,” he says. “In the Koran there is a dialogue between Allah and the Devil. And Allah doesn’t censor the devil.”

Which surah is he referring to here?

Comment: In a Way Allah does censor rather the devil even in that verse, because it is Allah who has narrated the incident. The devil is not just censored but even punished him for his arrogance. Hence the argument of that poet is without any base.

Comment: @Islam: Yes, but the point that Adonis is making is that he allowed him to speak and be heard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is referring to the story of the creation of Adam, where Allah orders the Angels to bow to Adam and Iblis refuses and argues with Allah against bowing to (what he perceives as) such a lowly creature.

> It is We Who created you and gave you shape; then We bade the angels
>   prostrate to Adam, and they prostrate; not so Iblis; He refused to be
>   of those who prostrate. (11)
>   (Allah) said: "What prevented thee from
>   prostrating when I commanded thee?" He said: "I am better than he:
>   Thou didst create me from fire, and him from clay." (12)
>   (Allah)
>   said: "Get thee down from this: it is not for thee to be arrogant
>   here: get out, for thou art of the meanest (of creatures)." (13)
>   He said: "Give me respite till the day they are raised up." (14)
>   (Allah) said: "Be thou among those who have respite." (15)
>   He said: "Because thou hast thrown me out of the way, lo! I will lie in wait
>   for them on thy straight way (16)
>   "Then will I assault them from before them and behind them, from their right and their left: Nor wilt thou find, in most of them, gratitude (for thy mercies)." (17)
>   (Allah) said: "Get out from this, disgraced and expelled. If any of
>   them follow thee,- Hell will I fill with you all. (18)

Al-A'raf (7:11-18)